# TDS error's occuring constantly (50mb log files in the space of 20secs)

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, glassfish, seam2

We are having an issue with a Seam application deployed to a Glassfish server, connecting to a MS SQL Server 2008 R1.

The glassfish server suddenly started logging the following error:

```
[#|2012-03-01T09:59:10.682+1300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.TOKEN 
    |_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-32;_RequestID=a1eaa1df-59f2-4eab-8f1f-aeeaf0915002;
    |ConnectionID:24617: batch completion: Encountered unexpected unknown token (0x30)|#]

[#|2012-03-01T09:59:10.682+1300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader
    |_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-32;_RequestID=a1eaa1df-59f2-4eab-8f1f-aeeaf0915002;
    |ConnectionID:24617 got unexpected value in TDS response at offset:12|#]

[#|2012-03-01T09:59:10.682+1300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.TOKEN
    |_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-38;_RequestID=86e50fbc-cde0-4ffe-a83e-4cca657f8669;
    |ConnectionID:24617: FetchBufferTokenHandler: Encountered unexpected unknown token (0x30)|#]

[#|2012-03-01T09:59:10.682+1300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader
    |_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-38;_RequestID=86e50fbc-cde0-4ffe-a83e-4cca657f8669;
    |ConnectionID:24617 got unexpected value in TDS response at offset:12|#]
```

We had to stop this being logged through glassfish as it got to 30GB before we we're able to stop.

We have not been able to find any reason for what could have caused this.

Has anyone anywhere seen this before??!

Comment: What version of java are you running?  JRE 1.6.0_29 and 30 have connection problems with MSSQL http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2011/11/07/supported-java-versions-november-2011.aspx  also  http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/696635/jdbc-connection-hangs-since-security-update-kb2539636  and  http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=cb38e57d1b6e357c8cc7cee5a357?bug_id=7103725

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jim, I don't think it is either version, and we have been through the compatibility issue with a previous version of java before. After a restart it's no longer happening, so guess I'll leave it in case anyone has the same problem

Comment: Hooray for the therapeutic restart.  Well now if you need a laugh, try this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8